# How can I write a function(a) which calls another function(b) when it completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I have a list of inputs(type="radio") and I'm running a animation when they're clicked, also I'm disabling the inputs whilst the animation is running.

How can I get this function to call another when its finished running?

```
function animation(para1, para2, para3, para4) {
   // calling a function to clear the animation for time before
   // this gets called when a input is clicked to run a animation
   // also hides inputs
}
```

I need to somehow call another function to re-enable the inputs once the animation is complete

Comment: You can use promise.

Comment: *"How can I write a function(a) which calls another function(b) when it completes?"* --> `function b(){ }; function a(){ b(); };`

Comment: @EddyAk it is complete when it reaches the last statement. `b();` is the final statement in `a`.

Comment: I tried this and it just went through all even through the animation is still running

Comment: @EddyAk Then you should rephrase your question. but when you do, this is going to be a duplicate. It is clear you haven't done any research. you're not the first person trying to do this.

Comment: How should I reword it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113926/discussion-between-edward-and-t-j).

Comment: @edward I don't think you can reword it without being a duplicate of existing questions. You can find an answer faster if you just do a google search with these keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback function... This is an example of callback function

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $("p").hide("slow", function(){
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use callbacks, which are just function parameters and have been around for quite some time, like so

```
function animation(para1, para2, para3, para4, callbackFn) {
  //do the work
  callbackFn(); //work is done, callback can be invoked now
}
```

or consider using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility), which are part of the ES6 standard. If using ES5 or below, there's libraries that can provide promises as well, such as [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: //work is done, callback can be invoked now. I know that this is what needs to do, I need to know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is an event when CSS animation ends. And CSS animations are better and faster then jQuery animations.

You can write your animations in CSS, use jQuery to set classes that start the animation and then wait for its end.

See how to [detect end of CSS animation](https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/)

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("animate");
  $(this).one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
    // Do something when the transition ends
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't even know what kind of animation OP is using. Either ask for clarifications or don't answer poor questions based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

@Radek Pech - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't taking into account the CSS animation timing, which made it look like the callback was being fired early.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Javascript [callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

In essence you can pass a function as a parameter to *another* function which can then execute it